# Audit とは何で、その日本語訳として適当なものは何ですか？

Tags: 討議, サポート, 翻訳

Traducir で string を眺めていると、"audit" という用語があるのに気付きました。

https://ja.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5BAa%5Dudit

Meta Stack Exchange で調べてみると [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/341401) に書かれており、レビューができるようになる前にレビューのテストを行う機能のようです。ただし日本語版では有効になっていないようで、しかも自分は他の Stack Exchange サイトでもこの機能に出会ったことがありません。機能のスクリーンショットなどがあれば翻訳の助けにしたいのですが、どこかにありませんでしょうか。

また、現状 "audit" には「監査」という言葉があてられているのですが、「監査」というのはいささか直訳すぎて実態に合っていないように思います。より適切な訳は無いでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

MSE の投稿を見る限り現時点で日本語版は対象外のようですし、翻訳の文字列も常に「日本語版で使われるものだけ」が追加されているわけでは無さそうなので (英語版での変更がそのままネットワークワイドに流れているだけ)、どういった場面で使われるのかがはっきりするまでは様子見 (=翻訳しない) でよいと個人的には思います。

Comment: 既に翻訳されているものがあるのは、とりあえず訳しただけなのかもですね……。